# Можно ли значения которая выдает функция засуть в массив и посчитать их сумму?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import math
def fibonachi():
    first=1
    last=2
    c=0
    print(last)
    while c<4000000:
        c=first+last
        first=last
        last=c
        if c%2==0:
            print(c)
```

fibonachi()
"""выдает значения
2
8
34
144
610
2584
10946
46368
196418
832040
3524578
можно ли эти значения засунуть в массив и посчитать их сумму?"""

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
import math
list1 = []
def fibonachi():
    first=1
    last=2
    c=0
    print(last)
    while c<4000000:
        c=first+last
        first=last
        last=c
        if c%2==0:
            list1.append(c)

fibonachi()
val = 0
for i in list1:
    val += i
print(val)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import math

def fibonachi():
    first = 1
    last = 2
    c = 0
    while c < 4000000:
        c = first + last
        first = last
        last = c
        if c % 2 == 0:
            yield c

s = sum(fibonachi())

print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, если я правильно понимаю:

```
import math
def fibonachi():
    mass = []
    first=1
    last=2
    c=0
    print(last)
    while c<4000000:
        c=first+last
        first=last
        last=c
        if c%2==0:
            mass.append(c)
    print(f'Сумма: {sum(mass)}')
    return sum(mass)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно

```
def fib(n):
    res=[2]
    a=1
    b=2
    c=0
    while c<=n:
        c=a+b
        a=b
        b=c
        if c%2==0:
            res.append(c)
    return res

print(fib(200))
print(sum(fib(200)))
```